# (Cadence) getting "deployment contains nonexisting contract" error when trying to deploy to Flow testnet

Tags: onflow-cadence

i'm trying to deploy a hello world smart contract to testnet. This is the contract I'm trying to deploy:

./contracts/NonFungibleToken.cdc

```swift
pub contract NonFungibleToken {
    // Declare a stored state field in HelloWorld
    //
    pub let greeting: String

    // Declare a function that can be called by anyone
    // who imports the contract
    //
    pub fun hello(): String {
        return self.greeting
    }

    init() {
        self.greeting = "Hello World!"
    }
}
```

This is my config file (flow.json):

```json
{
  "emulators": {
    "default": {
      "port": 3569,
      "serviceAccount": "emulator-account"
    }
  },
  "contracts": {
    "NonFungibleToken": "./contracts/NonFungibleToken.cdc"
  },
  "networks": {
    "emulator": "127.0.0.1:3569",
    "mainnet": "access.mainnet.nodes.onflow.org:9000",
    "testnet": "access.devnet.nodes.onflow.org:9000"
  },
  "accounts": {
    "emulator-account": {
      "address": "f8d6e0586b0a20c7",
      "key": "privatekey"
    },
    "testnet-account": {
      "address": "0x2ca684c2732d60e6",
      "key": "privatekey"
    }
  },
  "deployments": {
    "emulator": {
      "emulator-account": [
        "NonFungibleToken"
      ]
    },
    "testnet": {
      "testnet-account": [
        "NonFungibleToken"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to deploy, this is the error I get:

```sh
MacBook-Air:nft-app alberthu$ flow project deploy
❌ Config Error: deployment contains nonexisting contract NonFungbileToken
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ah the problem was that I needed to add the --network=testnet flag

`flow project deploy --network=testnet`